# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.AbstractModule not found by org.mybatis.mybatis-guice

Tags: osgi, mybatis, guice, java-11, apache-karaf

There is a problem that the bundle using mybatis-guice library using the felix framework fails to start.
The running environment is java11 and karaf 4.2.14 versions.

This is the corresponding error message.

```java
Error when instantiating bean daoService of class myApp.dao.inject.impl.ServiceImpl
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error when instantiating bean daoService of class myApp.dao.inject.impl.ServiceImpl
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.wrapAsCompDefEx(BeanRecipe.java:362)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromType(BeanRecipe.java:352)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:283)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:685)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:666)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:81)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:90)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:360)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:190)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:737)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:433)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:298)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:335)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:288)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:284)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:274)
            at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)
            at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)
            at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)
            at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)
            at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1179)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:730)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:485)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4579)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2174)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984)
            at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.BundleInstallSupportImpl.startBundle(BundleInstallSupportImpl.java:165)
            at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.startBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1154)
            at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:1044)
            at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1063)
            at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:998)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/AbstractModule
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2410)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2194)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1607)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2410)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2194)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1607)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1414)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1660)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1590)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2410)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2194)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1607)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
            at myApp.dao.inject.config.DaoModuleBindConfig$GameModule.configure(DaoModuleBindConfig.java:27)
            at com.google.inject.PrivateModule.configure(PrivateModule.java:102)
            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:409)
            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:108)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:160)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
            at myApp.dao.inject.impl.ServiceImple.<init>(ServiceImple.java:17)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:369)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.newInstance(BeanRecipe.java:839)
            at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromType(BeanRecipe.java:350)
            \... 36 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.AbstractModule not found by org.mybatis.mybatis-guice [160]
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1639)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
            ... 83 more
```

The following is a list of the dependencies and import packages used by the bundle.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-guice</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Import-Package>
                    !junit.framework*,
                    !org.junit*,
                    !org.mockito*,
                    !org.checkerframework.*,
                    org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml,
                    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc,
                    *;
                </Import-Package>
                <Embed-Dependency/>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <DynamicImport>*</DynamicImport>
                <Export-Package>myApp.dao.*;version=${project.version};-noimport:=true
                </Export-Package>
                <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                <_versionpolicy>[$(version;==;$(@)),$(version;+;$(@)))</_versionpolicy>
                <effective>effective:=active</effective>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The version information for dependencies is defined in parent POM.

also added bootdelegation according to the [guice osgi wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/OSGi)

> set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true -Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=`org.aopalliance.*`,`com.google.inject.*`

Written in karaf.bat file.

Just in case, I specified the package in the bootdelegation in the karaf config.property accoding to the [karaf container 4.x - 4.14.7. Security providers](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/)

> org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation = 
> com.sun.*, 
> javax.transaction, 
> javax.transaction.xa, 
> javax.xml.crypto, 
> javax.xml.crypto.*, 
> jdk.nashorn.*, 
> sun.*, 
>
> jdk.internal.reflect, 
>
> jdk.internal.reflect.*, 
> org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal, 
> org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot, 
> `org.aopalliance`, 
> `org.aopalliance.*`, 
> `com.google.inject`, 
> `com.google.inject.*`, 
> `com.google.common`, 
> `com.google.common.*`, 
> `org.mybatis.guice`, 
> `org.mybatis.guice.*`

Nevertheless, the classloader still says the class cannot be found.

| ID | State | Lvl | Version | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | Active | 80 | 5.1.0 | guice |
| 159 | Active | 80 | 3.5.9 | mybatis |
| 160 | Active | 80 | 3.17.0 | mybatis-guice |

It is confirmed that the guice, mybatis, and mybatis-guice are also active.

What else can i try?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: import package and
After defining the export package in more detail, it started to work well.

That was my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the error message:

```
com.google.inject.AbstractModule not found by org.mybatis.mybatis-guice
```

Suggests that the `org.mybatis.mybatis-guice` bundle should import package `com.google.inject` but fails to do so. As such, all the mitigations you have added to your own bundle such as `DynamicImport` (which isn't a valid OSGi header anyway) will not do anything because it is the third-party bundle which is at fault.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering me.

when start the bundle after removing the invalid osgi header `DynamicImport` as your advice, encountered countless via two dependency chains logs. **First** there was a problem that the AbstractModule could not be imported due to incorrect package connection by `Dynamicimport`.
**Second** after removing `Dynamicimport`, can I consider it as the first step to import the AbstractModule normally with the correct dependency instruction?
Also, could you tell me the right way to solve the dependency chain or provide me with a sample code?

Comment: `60│ Active│80│5.1.0│guice , 60 | com/google/inject/AbstractModule.class | exported: true`
`111│Failure│80│0.0.1.SNAPSHOT│myApp , 111 | com/google/inject/AbstractModule.class | exported: false` I confirmed in my bundle that the package is exported:false. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Thanks to you, I was able to test a few other things that I hadn't thought about.

In conclusion, it failed, and I'm going to recreate the bundle without using Google guice.

Thank you so much for your advice.